# Javascript slice concatenation

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I need to bump a string down 1 index thus moving index 0 to the back.

For example, turn the string '12345' into '23451'.  The code below **works** but I just don't understand why/how.

How does the return statement remember to add '345' back into string `s`?  Shouldn't it be returning the concatenation '21'?

```
let s = "12345"
let rotate = (function (){
    return s.slice(1) + s.slice(0,1);
})

console.log(rotate(s))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Shouldn't it be returning the concatenation '21'?"*

`s.slice(1)` does not return an element at index `1`, but **everything** that starts from index `1`. So in your case it will stand for `2345` and finally will result in `23451`.

Comment: `2345`, actually.

Answer (score 0):

The slice takes two arguments. If there is only one argument present, it will return the string FROM the first index (missing everything before that). If there are two arguments present, it will return a string containing the characters between the two indices. For this example, it is the first character (from 0 to 1). Then it just adds these two parts together and returns it.

You can read more about the [slice function on Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).